# Onmouseover onmouseout image change Liquid effect

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap

I need to realize image change with liquid effect like in [**here**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/MPNoZd?editors=1010)

I have a simple block with image I need to change this image (to other image) in `onmouseover` with this effect and return to initial position in `onmouseout` also using this effect

```js
const avatarQuantumBreak = document.querySelector(".avatar_quantum_break");
const avatar = document.querySelector(".avatar");

avatarQuantumBreak.style.opacity = "0";

let hover = () => avatarQuantumBreak.style.opacity = "1";
let normal = () => avatarQuantumBreak.style.opacity = "0";

avatar.onmouseover = () => hover();
avatar.onmouseout = () => normal();
```

```css
html , body {
  height:100%;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 195px;
}
.avatar_simple,
.avatar_quantum_break {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
.avatar .avatar_simple img,
.avatar .avatar_quantum_break img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 86%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/97/three.min.js"></script>


<div class=avatar>
    <span class=avatar_simple>
        <img src="https://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/fashion/daily/2014/05/27/27-amber-heard.w330.h330.jpg">
    </span>
    <span class=avatar_quantum_break>
        <img src="https://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/daily/vulture/2016/05/31/31-amber-heard.w330.h330.jpg">
    </span>
</div>
```

Image `transition` function which trigger's **liquid  animation**  is below

```
transitionNext() {
    TweenMax.to(this.mat.uniforms.dispPower, 2.5, {
      value: 1,
      ease: Expo.easeInOut,
      onUpdate: this.render,
      onComplete: () => {
        this.mat.uniforms.dispPower.value = 0.0
        this.changeTexture()
        this.render.bind(this)
        this.state.animating = false
      }
    })
```

I try to use this function but this didn't help me.

Also I try to change images in this `Array`  line **15**  but this also didn't helped.

```
this.images = [ //1
      'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg1.jpg',
      'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg2.jpg',
      'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg3.jpg'
    ]
```

This function start's the animation

```
listeners() {
   window.addEventListener('wheel', this.nextSlide, { passive: true })
}
```

**Next slide** function

```
nextSlide() {
   if (this.state.animating) return

   this.state.animating = true

   this.transitionNext()

   this.data.current = this.data.current === this.data.total ? 0 : this.data.current + 1
this.data.next = this.data.current === this.data.total ? 0 : this.data.current + 1
}
```

Please help..

Comment: why havent you used same code in codepen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice one - realtime vfx meets web development :)

All magic of this effect is done with GLSL shader (you can see it at the bottom of example html)
here I've added some comments to it

```
  // next lines are input data that gpu gets form javascript
  varying vec2 vUv; // uv coordinate of current pixel
  uniform sampler2D texture1; // picture 1
  uniform sampler2D texture2; // picture 2
  uniform sampler2D disp; // noise texture
  uniform float dispPower; // effect progress
  uniform float intensity; // effect scale

  void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;

    vec4 disp = texture2D(disp, uv); // read noise texture
    vec2 dispVec = vec2(disp.x, disp.y); // get red and green values

    // calculate uv displacement
    vec2 distPos1 = uv + (dispVec * intensity * dispPower); 
    vec2 distPos2 = uv + (dispVec * -(intensity * (1.0 - dispPower)));

    // sample images with displaced uv
    vec4 _texture1 = texture2D(texture1, distPos1); 
    vec4 _texture2 = texture2D(texture2, distPos2);

    // mix both pictures using effect dispPower value and output pixel color
    gl_FragColor = mix(_texture1, _texture2, dispPower);
  }
```

it takes 3 textures as an input: picture1 picture2 and noise texture used to distort uv
and generates a color value for one pixel of one frame of transition effect on the fly on GPU
this shader applied to all pixels of the surface

a technique used here called "Texture Distortion" or "UV Displacement" 
the idea is to Adjust UV coordinates with data stored in noise texture.

the good place to start learning GLSL is https://thebookofshaders.com/

GLSL reference http://www.shaderific.com/glsl/

also, I suggest visiting https://www.shadertoy.com/

And welcome to the magical world of real-time vfx

Comment: here is a noise texture that controls this effect https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/rock-_disp.png